New Outlook calendar Skype and Teams meeting event
I have two Microsoft accounts, one personal and one from my institution.
In my personal account, I can connect and event to the calendar to Skype.
And from my institution I can connect it only to Teams.
is there a way to connect the event from my institution to Skype?
I am using the New Outlook.
Thanks



This question could use more information, your problem is pretty much unclear

You say your institution account only connects to Teams, and then you ask if there's any way to connect your institution account to Teams. Your question does not make sense. Also, your institution controls what your institution accounts can and cannot connect to, so you should start by asking them.

@music2myear yes, you are right to Skype.

I have the same situation as you. In personal accounts there are only Skype, and organizational accounts are Teams meetings. Then I gathered the official documentation, which indicated that the Skype option would automatically open when outlook.com account was added to the account, which I thought might be by design.
In addition, using Skype and Teams is also relevant to the setup within your organization, depending on what your organization supports. We recommend that you contact your organization administrator.
Reference:https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/office/create-or-schedule-an-online-meeting-in-outlook-for-windows-b8305620-d16e-4667-989d-4a977aad6556
